# error: cannot open file 'boost_atomic-vc120-mt-1_58.lib' boost libs on Qt Windows8

Tags: c++, qt, boost

I am trying to build link boost library with Qt creator on windows. And I have downloaded boost prebuilt library compiled with msvc-12.0.

In my .pro file I have added

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:/local/boost_1_58_0/boost
LIBS += "-LC:/local/boost_1_58_0/stage/lib" -lboost_atomic-vc120-mt-1_58
```

But while building the project I am getting the error  `error: LNK1104: cannot open file 'boost_atomic-vc120-mt-1_58.lib'`

My Qt version is `Desktop Qt 5.4.1 MSVC2013 64bit`

And the compiler list showing

[image]

I have downloaded boost library from http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.58.0/

and I choose `boost_1_58_0-msvc-12.0-64.exe` as I am using msvc-2013 as my compiler.

**Edit:** 
Compile output

```
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-lvda'
    cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -FS -lvda -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -EHsc /Fddebug\AcessControl-V1.pdb -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_QUICK_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_QML_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I"..\AcessControl-V34-DVR" -I"." -I"..\AcessControl-V24\ffmpeg\include" -I"C:\local\boost_1_58_0\boost" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\msvc2013_64\include" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\msvc2013_64\include\QtQuick" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\msvc2013_64\include\QtWidgets" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\msvc2013_64\include\QtGui" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\msvc2013_64\include\QtANGLE" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\msvc2013_64\include\QtQml" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\msvc2013_64\include\QtNetwork" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\msvc2013_64\include\QtSql" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\msvc2013_64\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc2013" -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\vapplica\AppData\Local\Temp\moc_alert.obj.5536.20297.jom
moc_alert.cpp
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-lvda'
    link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST:embed /OUT:debug\AcessControl-V1.exe @C:\Users\vapplica\AppData\Local\Temp\AcessControl-V1.exe.5536.23406.jom
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'boost_atomic-vc120-mt-1_58.lib'
jom: E:\Qt_Project\AcessControl-V34\Makefile.Debug [debug\AcessControl-V1.exe] Error 1104
jom: E:\Qt_Project\AcessControl-V34\Makefile [debug] Error 2
16:52:42: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project AcessControl-V1 (kit: Desktop Qt 5.4.1 MSVC2013 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
16:52:42: Elapsed time: 00:24.
```

Does any one know why this error occurs?

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks 
Haris

Comment: does the file `boost_atomic-vc120-mt-1_58.lib` exist in the specified directory?

Comment: seems you download x86 prebuilt libraries, but use x64 compiler.

Comment: @m.s Yes the library exist on my C:\local\boost_1_58_0\stage\lib folder.

Comment: @Jichao I have downloaded `boost_1_58_0-msvc-12.0-64.exe` as specified in my question.

Comment: @Haris turn on the verbose mode, see the detailed command for linking.

Comment: I have added more compiler output see my edit.

Comment: Also I cannot see an include folder inside my boost directory.

Comment: @Haris: `boost_1_58_0` is your relative include folder, so #include <boost/xx.hpp> map to boost_1_58_0/boost/xx.hpp. And I also need the temp jom file `@C:\Users\vapplica\AppData\Local\Temp\AcessControl-V1.exe.5536.23406.jom`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77793/discussion-between-haris-and-jichao).

Comment: @Jichao Is this because the jom file missing, if so how can I fix it.

Comment: I figure it out that I didn't add lib before my library as my original lib name was `libboost_atomic-vc120-mt-1_58.lib`, that is I changed `-lboost_atomic-vc120-mt-1_58` to `-llibboost_atomic-vc120-mt-1_58`

Answer (score 1):

In your pro file change `INCLUDE` and `LIBS` directives:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:/local/boost_1_58_0
LIBS += -LC:/local/boost_1_58_0/stage/lib
```

Make shore that `.lib` files in `C:/local/boost_1_58_0/stage/lib` directory. Also make shore that header files in `C:/local/boost_1_58_0/boost` directory. You need add `C:/local/boost_1_58_0` to `INCLUDEPATH` for be able to write `#include <boost/...>` in your program.

By default boost use auto-linking. You do not need to indicate library name. If you want disable auto-linking specify `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB` for preprocessor.